# is there any succesful way to grow taller after age of seventeen

Tags: growth-hormones

I'm seventeen years old both my parents are short. is there any way for me to grow taller. i mocked by most of people because of height.anyone plz tell me succesful way to grow taller

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Please take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help). Please try to edit your question with the help of ["how to ask"](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

### No, there isn’t.

> How much variation (difference between individuals) in height is attributable to genetic effects and how much to nutritional effects?" **The short answer to this question is that about 60 to 80 percent of the difference in height between individuals is determined by genetic factors, whereas 20 to 40 percent can be attributed to environmental effects, mainly nutrition.** This answer is based on estimates of the "heritability" of human height: the proportion of the total variation in height due to genetic factors.
>
> Can special treatment and nutrient supplements increase the height further? The answer is yes. The most important nutrient for final height is **protein in childhood**. Minerals, in particular calcium, and vitamins A and D also influence height. Because of this, malnutrition in childhood is detrimental to height.
>
> <sup>[Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-much-of-human-height/)</sup>

Comment: so there is no way to grow taller at age 17 for me

Comment: is that the herbal medicine ashwagandha  help me to become height

Comment: Some males don't finish growing to final height until age 20 or so.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Yeah, but that’s not really the question. I thought OP meant whether he could actively increase his final height, which they can’t. Whether they continue to grow significantly or not is not anyone’s decision, but already determined by the diet when OP was a toddler and by the genes